# Internal working of Tkinter after method

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working Tkinter GUI for quite sometime. And I was wondering, how `after` method actually works on it. My questions are very simple.

1. How `after` method is implemented internally in Tkinter ?
2. Are `after` calls threaded ?
3. What are the cons (if any) of multiple `after` calls in Tkinter ?
4. How are `after` callbacks scheduled ?

I did go through a couple of links like [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm). But couldn't get these informations.

Answer (score 3):

1. `after()` calls Tck/Tk's `after` command, which registers a callback to be called later by the Tcl/Tk event loop.
2. `after()` calls are not threaded.
3. One issue is that a blocking or long-running operation may cause something scheduled with `after()` to run significantly later than you meant. There are many more possible pros and cons which may be relevant, but you'll need to specify your concerns or use cases...
4. A callback is registered into Tcl/Tk event loop, which takes care of the scheduling. For details on how that works, see [the documentation](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1527).

### Explanation:

As you may already know, Tkinter uses [Tcl/Tk](https://www.tcl.tk/) internally.

Taking a look at [the code for the `after()` method](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#l583), it appears that Tkinter is just calling the Tcl/Tk `after` command.

The [documentation for Tcl/Tk's `after` command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/after.htm) doesn't mention anything about threads. This makes sense given [Tcl/Tk's single-threaded event loop design](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/thread_model.html).

So, my conclusion is that Tkinter's `after()` method does *not* use threads, rather it just registers a callback using the internal Tcl/Tk `after` command, which will be called at the most appropriate time possible by the [Tcl/Tk event loop](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1527).

Answer (score 0):

It's really quite simple: Tkinter maintains a queue of work to be done (the event queue), and `mainloop` (as well as `update`) processes that queue. `after` merely adds a timestamped event to the queue. No threads are involved.

Comment: The events are not in a queue; a different data structure is used. And even if it were a queue, the events could be processed by threads. The real point is that a single-threaded event loop design is used, but the way you worded your answer fails to make that clear.

Comment: How can I make "no threads are involved" any clearer? And while another data structure may actually be used internally, conceptually it is just a queue of events. Thanks for the comment, though.

Comment: Sorry if my previous comment came out overly antagonistic, I didn't mean it to be so. You wrote "No threads are involved" after a previous sentence which stated that the events are just in a queue. That gives the impression that the first sentence explains why no threads are involved, but that's not the case.